# how to create a user with root privilege and fix this error?

Tags: ssh, root, su

I created an user with root access

```
useradd -ou 0 -g 0 myuser -p [12345]
```

when I try to su to new user, it's show me :

```
: No such file or directory
```

when I want to connect to that via ssh it's show me :

```
Permission denied, please try again.
```

so I checked my passwd it was :

```
myuser:x:0:0::/home/myuser:/bin/bash
```

so for test I created another user without root access and it's worked very well.

Also in sudoers I changed , but it's won't work again

```
root ALL=(ALL) ALL
myuser ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

then I changed `PermitRootLogin` in sshd_config but it won't work :(

please help me, I want to create a user with root access and connect to it under ssh connection !

Answer (score 2):

Usually one **does not** create users "with root privileges" that way. One creates a *normal* account, with a non-zero UID, and uses tools like `su`, `sudo`, `ksu`, `pkexec` and such, to obtain the root privileges when needed.

For that, just `useradd myuser` would be enough.

... That said, the current problem is most likely that `useradd -p` expects the *hashed* password, like `$5$ljURL2H7MlEqHoMg$/8qvFv8…3Upazq9`, and if a plain-text one gets stored in `/etc/passwd`, the system won't actually accept it.

Another problem is that the user is missing a home directory. If you use `useradd`, you must either specify the `-m` option, or create+chown the homedir manually.

Finally, some systems are configured through PAM to forbid root (uid 0) logins *everywhere*, even if sshd's config allows that. This is again to prevent people from doing stupid things like giving uid 0 to regular user accounts (whether intentionally or accidentally).

So, first fix the UID (delete and re-add the account), then use `passwd myuser` to set the password.

Comment: thanks for your reply , yeah I know that and I stored hash , and actually as I told I create an user in normal mode but when I change that to root it won't work , my question is why ?

Comment: Ah, yeah, updated it a little.